# Gulp sass not showing any css errors

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-sass

```
    var gulp         = require('gulp');
    var requireDir   = require('require-dir');
    var path         = require('path');
    var $            = require('gulp-load-plugins')({pattern:['gulp-*','gulp.*']});


   gulp.task('sass', function() {
    var scriptsPath = './';

    gulp.src(path.join(scriptsPath, '/src/sass/**/*.scss'))
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe($.sass({
        includePaths: [
            path.join(scriptsPath, '/src/sass/'),
            'bower_components/bourbon/app/assets/stylesheets',
            'bower_components/neat/app/assets/stylesheets'
        ],
        outputStyle: "compressed"
    }).on('error', $.sass.logError))
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.write('./'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('website/static/css/'));
});

gulp.task('build', ['build-js-libs', 'sass']);
```

If I enter any bad css in the .scss files no error is being shown in the terminal on a build - have I done something wrong with what I am using above? Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test this, but would outputting the error to console.log work?

```
...
}).on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
})
...
```

You can also use [gulp-plumber](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-plumber) before the sass-function. That would log the error to the console

```
...
.pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
.pipe($.plumber())
.pipe($.sass({
...
```